# Component not pushing data into array

Tags: reactjs

I've created a component for my project and for some reason whenever the data is not updating when pushing data to array. It only pushes it once and it does the last object only. It doesn't stop the loop or skips to the end, so I have no clue what is causing it. The format is correct but the data simply does not push into the array.

This is my component
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-bartik-bh9rc

```
class Organization extends Component {
  render () {  
   const team = (props) => {
      let arr = [];

      props.props.map((res, key) => {
        let teamName = res.team.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase();
        if (Object.keys(arr) !== teamName) {
          arr[teamName] = {};
          arr[teamName]['section_title'] = res.team;
        }
        arr[teamName]['fields'] = res
      });

      return arr;
    }

    return (
      <div className="press-wrapper">
        <Cards data={team(this.props)} multiple={true} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

this is the current output

```
{
  co_founder: {
    section_title: 'Co Founder',
    fields: [
      { title: "Cl Tre, Co-Founder & COO", team: "Co Founder" },
    ]
  }
},
{
  team_member: {
    section_title: 'Team Member',
    fields: [
      { title: "Team Member", team: "Team Member" },
    ]
  }
},
{
  advisor: {
    section_title: 'Advisor',
    fields: [
      { title: "Team Member", team: "Advisor" },
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my desired output

```
   {
      co_founder: {
        section_title: 'Co Founder',
        fields: [
          { title: "Ja Ris, Co-Founder & CEO", team: "Co Founder" },
          { title: "Cl Tre, Co-Founder & COO", team: "Co Founder" },
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      team_member: {
        section_title: 'Team Member',
        fields: [
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Team Member" },
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Team Member" },
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Team Member" },
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Team Member" },
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Team Member" },
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Team Member" },
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      advisor: {
        section_title: 'Advisor',
        fields: [
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Advisor" },
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Advisor" },
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Advisor" },
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Advisor" },
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Advisor" },
          { title: "Team Member", team: "Advisor" },
        ]
      }
    },
```

Comment: So do you want the `fields` arrays in the output object to contain all _unique_ titles in the props data? Or just use the latest one it comes across as iterating through the data? Cos based on your sample output, it seems like the latter

Comment: I added my desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a reduction to build up the custom object based on the `props`. Something like this should help get your desired output:

```
props.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let teamName = curr.team.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase();
  if (!acc[teamName]) {
    acc[teamName] = {};
    acc[teamName].section_title = curr.team;
    acc[teamName].fields = [curr.title];
  }
  else {
    acc[teamName].fields.push(curr.title);
  }
  return acc;
}, {})
```